# Get window view including actionbar?

Tags: android

How do I access the ViewGroup, including the ActionBar but excluding the status bar?

So, `activity.getWindow().getDecorView()` returns me everything, including the status bar.

but `activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)` returns me the viewgroup underneath the actionbar.

What's the middle step?

Answer (score 1):

As you've found out, this ViewGroup will also include the status bar:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
```

However there is no ViewGroup in between as we can see from this *Dumped View Hierarchy*:

[image]

Comment: @Vee I've checked it out, and it turns out there's no intermediate ViewGroup between those, it's shown in a picture i've added.